# Divide One Pandas Dataframe by Another - Ignore index but respect columns

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I have 2 dataframes. 
I would like to broadcast a divide operation

```
df1= pd.DataFrame([[1.,2.,3.,4.], [5.,6.,7.,8.], [9.,10.,11.,12.]],
                  columns=['A','B','C','D'], index=['x','y','z'])

df2= pd.DataFrame([[0.,1.,2.,3.]], columns=['A','B','D','C'], index=['q'])
```

Notice that the columns are aligned slightly differently in df2.

I would like to divide df1 by df2 where the row is broadcast but the column labels are respected.

```
   A   B   C   D
x  1   2   3   4
y  5   6   7   8
z  9  10  11  12


   A  B  D  C
q  0  1  2  3
```

This would be wrong.

```
df1.values/df2.values

[[         inf   2.           1.5          1.33333333]
 [         inf   6.           3.5          2.66666667]
 [         inf  10.           5.5          4.        ]]
```

Answer I desire is:

```
   A    B   C      D
x  inf  2   1      2
y  inf  6   2.33   4
z  inf  10  3.66   6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you divide by a Series (by selecting that one row of the second dataframe), pandas will align this series on the columns of the first dataframe, giving the desired result:

```
In [75]: df1 / df2.loc['q']
Out[75]:
     A   B         C  D
x  inf   2  1.000000  2
y  inf   6  2.333333  4
z  inf  10  3.666667  6
```

If you don't know/want to use the name of that one row, you can use [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) to convert the one-column dataframe to a series: `df1 / df2.squeeze()` (see answer of @EdChum).

Answer (score 2):

May be, you could order your `df2` columns same of `df1` and then divide on values

```
In [53]: df1.values/df2[df1.columns].values
Out[53]:
array([[         inf,   2.        ,   1.        ,   2.        ],
       [         inf,   6.        ,   2.33333333,   4.        ],
       [         inf,  10.        ,   3.66666667,   6.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder the column and then call `squeeze` to flatten the array and then call `div`:

```
In [114]:

df1= pd.DataFrame( [[1.,2.,3.,4.],[5.,6.,7.,8.],[9.,10.,11.,12.]] ,columns = ['A','B','C','D'], index = ['x','y','z'])
df2= pd.DataFrame( [[0.,1.,2.,3.]] ,columns = ['A','B','D','C'], index = ['q'])    ​
df1.div(df2.ix[:,df1.columns].squeeze())

Out[114]:
     A   B         C  D
x  inf   2  1.000000  2
y  inf   6  2.333333  4
z  inf  10  3.666667  6
```

`df1/df2.ix[:,df1.columns].squeeze()` also works but @Joris's answer is much nicer

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @joris the column reordering is unnecessary as pandas will naturally align against the columns anyway so:

```
df1.div(df2squeeze())
```

or

```
df1./df2squeeze()
```

would work

Comment: @EdChum you don't need the `.ix[:,df1.columns]` part when using `div`, as this aligns the indices automatically: just `df1.div(df2.squeeze())` works as well (which is also a nice solution!)

Comment: @joris yeah was overthinking this, I like fancy indexing a bit too much, will update, thanks